# How to receive dbus signal 'org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor.DriveConnected' using java?

Tags: java, ubuntu, dbus

I've struggling for some time trying to get dbus signal. I'm using java 1.8 with https://github.com/hypfvieh/dbus-java version 3.2.4. The goal is just to get mentioned signal my code:

```
package pl.thetosters.szafagra.dbus;

import org.freedesktop.dbus.connections.impl.DBusConnection;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusException;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.interfaces.DBusSigHandler;
import org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor;

public class DBusSupport {
  private DBusConnection conn;

  public DBusSupport() {
    try {
      conn = DBusConnection.getConnection(DBusConnection.DBusBusType.SESSION);
      conn.addSigHandler(RemoteVolumeMonitor.DriveConnected.class, new DBusSigHandler<RemoteVolumeMonitor.DriveConnected>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(RemoteVolumeMonitor.DriveConnected driveConnected) {
          System.out.println("------OK");
        }
      });
    } catch (DBusException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
package org.gtk.Private;

import org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusException;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.interfaces.DBusInterface;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.messages.DBusSignal;

public class RemoteVolumeMonitor implements DBusInterface {

  public class DriveConnected extends DBusSignal {
    public DriveConnected(String path, String s, Object arg) throws DBusException {
      super(path, s, arg);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isRemote() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String getObjectPath() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

When I plug in USB pen I got response, I see on console following things:

```
2021-02-20 16:31:15 DEBUG InputStreamMessageReader:179 - => DBusSignal [clazz=null]
2021-02-20 16:31:15 DEBUG DBusConnection:857 - Handling incoming signal: DBusSignal [clazz=null]
2021-02-20 16:31:15 DEBUG DBusSignal:196 - Converting signal to type: class org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor$DriveConnected
2021-02-20 16:31:15 WARN  DBusConnection:912 - Exception while running signal handler 'pl.thetosters.szafagra.dbus.DBusSupport$1@5383c3b0' for signal 'DBusSignal [clazz=class org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor$DriveConnected]':
org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.messages.DBusSignal.createReal(DBusSignal.java:247)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.connections.AbstractConnection$3.run(AbstractConnection.java:903)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.messages.DBusSignal.createReal(DBusSignal.java:240)
    ... 4 more
2021-02-20 16:31:15 DEBUG Error:143 - Creating message with serial 4
2021-02-20 16:31:15 DEBUG Error:848 - Appending sig: yyyy data: [108, 3, 0, 1]
2021-02-20 16:31:15 DEBUG Error:848 - Appending sig: ua(yv) data: [4, [[4, [s, org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusExecutionException]], [5, [u, 835]], [6, [s, :1.33]], [8, [g, s]]]]
2021-02-20 16:31:15 DEBUG Error:848 - Appending sig: s data: [Error handling signal org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor.DriveConnected: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch]
2021-02-20 16:31:15 DEBUG OutputStreamMessageWriter:34 - <= Error(0,4) { Error Name=>org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusExecutionException, Reply Serial=>835, Destination=>:1.33, Signature=>s } { Error handling signal org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor.DriveConnected: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch }
```

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. I tried to change DriveConnected constructor into several variants non work. If it's different then this one I got other error:

```
DBusSignal:226 - Could not find suitable constructor for class org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor$DriveConnected with argument-types: [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.Object;]
```

So I'm guessing that the signature is ok (since arguments match what I see on console when running dbus-monitor). What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
log from dbus-monitor showing `MountAdded` message

```
signal time=1613978013.675766 sender=:1.33 -> destination=(null destination) serial=980 path=/org/gtk/Private/RemoteVolumeMonitor; interface=org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor; member=MountAdded
   string "org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor"
   string "0x7f645c015c80"
   struct {
      string "0x7f645c015c80"
      string "3,9 GB Volume"
      string ". GThemedIcon drive-removable-media-usb drive-removable-media drive-removable drive"
      string ". GThemedIcon drive-removable-media-usb-symbolic drive-removable-media-symbolic drive-removable-symbolic drive-symbolic drive-removable-media-usb drive-removable-media drive-removable drive"
      string ""
      string "file:///media/bar/6A90-7B00"
      boolean true
      string "0x5620577283d0"
      array [
      ]
      string "gvfs.time_detected_usec.1613978013673952"
      array [
      ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem during the deserialization of parameters. Maybe you're sending the signal in a bad format on the other side.
Actually on this side you're waiting for a signal as "DriveConnected "pippo" Object" which can be a problem because DBUS is not able to deserialize.

1st Attempt try to remove Object on the constructor and on client side check if you are sending DriveConnected /from_path_1 "pippo"

Comment: This signal is send by system app. When you run ```dbus-monitor --session --monitor``` and then plug in USB pen you will see this signal as emitted. I can't change format of this signal.

Comment: Can you post the message that you see on dbus-monitor when you plug in the usb pen?

Comment: I edited initial question to add this log. It was to long to fit as comment.

Comment: I confirm it's not able to convert the struct into Object. You must create a class which will contain all fields inside the struct that you see on dbus-monitor. 
DBus works only on callback with good serialization.
After you create USBInfo class you should provide that class at your DriveConnected constructor signature instead of Object arg

Comment: You should create your struct object as showed here ==> https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/dbus-java/dbus-javase7.html#x24-280007.6

Comment: Yeah, I tried but I failed when I get to point where is array of map. Currently I dropped this approach and used different way to detect that USB Pen is mounted.

Comment: If you need only to detect USB pen, maybe dbus is not the easiest method. The I2C library should be better idea.